# Magento 1.9.1 + Patch SUPEE 6788 breaks custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

Last day I Install Patch SUPEE 6788 then my website is blank also widget block so i am very stress please help me how can i resolve it

Comment: You can try using [this tool kit](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox) that was created specifically for this patch. It should be able to automatically fix your whitelists for you.

Comment: i apply @7ochem your question but cannot resolve this issue thats why ask for new question

Comment: @travisw i see your link but this link apply for ssh but i have no access in ssh can you please tell me how can i upload via ftp

Answer (score 1):

What happens to me is that my apache server doesn't permit the `.htaccess` modifications that the Patch adds.

Try comment this lines in the `.htaccess` file:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

Comment: i already add this in my website .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted your cms blocks and variables as described in: "APPSEC-1057" [SUPEE-6788](https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details.pdf). You can do this in system->permissions->{variables and blocks}

Also you can create an upgrade script that will take care of this:

```
/** @var  $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/*
 * Make sure the upgrade is not performed on installations without the tables
 * (i.e. unpatched shops).
 */
$adminVersion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Mage_Admin')->version;
if (version_compare($adminVersion, '1.6.1.2', '>=')) {

    $blockNames = array(
        'cms/block',
        'catalog/product_list',
        'page/html'
    );
    foreach ($blockNames as $blockName) {
        $whitelistBlock = Mage::getModel('admin/block')->load($blockName, 'block_name');
        $whitelistBlock->setData('block_name', $blockName);
        $whitelistBlock->setData('is_allowed', 1);
        $whitelistBlock->save();
    }

    $variableNames = array(
        'design/email/logo_alt',
        'design/email/logo_width',
        'design/email/logo_height',
    );

    foreach ($variableNames as $variableName) {
        $whitelistVar = Mage::getModel('admin/variable')->load($variableName, 'variable_name');
        $whitelistVar->setData('variable_name', $variableName);
        $whitelistVar->setData('is_allowed', 1);
        $whitelistVar->save();
    }
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: i apply this "APPSEC-1057" in my website but can please tell me which file i update this code

Comment: if you are not sure how to use upgrade scripts then simply whitelist your blocks using magento admin panel: system->permissions->{variables and blocks}

Comment: i already implement this solution but still no results

Comment: can you please tell me which file i update this code

Comment: this script is doing the same that you are doing manually from the admin, so if you already did it manually there is no need to add the script. If you still want to do it, then put this into a data folder in one of your existing modules, I have no space to explain here so read this: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/